# Counting Number of Properties Inside Objects Inside an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
var obj = [{"name":"doop"}, {"name": "coop"}, {"name": "woof"}]
```

I would like to count how many properties are inside each object (in this example it should just be one for each.

I have tried:

```
/* function getEnteriesPerRowCount(_obj){
  _obj.forEach(function(element){
  console.log("checking objects")
    element.forEach(function(prop){
        console.log("checking prop")
    })
  })
} */
```

Which from what I have been reading on SO won't work as I am not specifying exactly which property in the `element.forEach`. The program will stop at the first iteration of `checking objects`

Comment: Use `Object.keys()` to get the array of keys in an object. `arr.forEach(function(obj) { console.log(Object.keys(obj).length); });`

Comment: Ah great thanks. works great. I was wondering if there was a nested loop way of doing it though too

Comment: why would you WANT a nested loop? besides, if you look at the [polyfill for Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill) you'll see you technically have a nested loop already :p

Comment: @Joromanda I see what you are saying. no huge problem I just like seeing it looping

Comment: note, `Object.keys` doesn't enumerate the prototype chain, so you wont necessarily get the same results as if you used a `for...in` loop

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = [{"name":"doop"}, {"name": "coop"}, {"name": "woof"}]

obj.map(function (each){
console.log(Object.keys(each).length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A hasOwnProperty check needed to be in-place otherwise it wouldn't work

```
function getEnteriesPerRowCount(_obj){
  _obj.forEach(function(element){
  console.log("checking objects")
  console.log(element)
    for (var property in element){
      if (element.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log("has prop")
      }
    }
    })
  }
```

Comment: unless you want to count properties in the prototype chain